# Agrupación de Datos Repetidos en MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hola tengo el siguientes tablas en MySQL:

**Tabla Parques**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla Promotor**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla Actividades Adicionales**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla Actividades Adicionales con vinculación de Parques**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora genero un consulta multi-tabla el cual me traera el `idPromotor`,`NombreParque`,`Act_Adicional`,`ComisionDeActividadAdicional` relacionando el `id` perteneciente de las tablas con **`Inner Join`** y obtengo el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen de arriba se repiten los promotores pues en cada parque se tiene diferente actividad adicional disponible. Y en si mi pregunta es ¿que hago para que no me repita el `idPromotor` varias veces, que se vean las actvidades adicionales, parque al que pertenecen y sus respectivas comisiones?, o ¿la consulta esta bien hecha?, basicamente como obtengo los mismos resultados sin tener repetido el `idPromotor`.

Perdón la molestia.

Comment: si la tengo agregado, en la ultima imagen, es un select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intenta agregar una instruccion DISTINCT antes de los campos que llamas, seria algo asi:

```
SELECT DISTINCT promotor.idPromotor, parques.Nombre, ........
```